# Why is Firefox on Ubuntu choppier than Firefox on Windows?

Tags: firefox, nvidia

I have nvidia driver on both OSs. Same FF version. Both with smooth scrolling enabled. Using FF in windows is a big joy! It's so smooth, like a hot knife slicing butter. Ubuntu's FF is somewhat choppier. I realize this may be the driver as sometimes i see tearing in Ubuntu. I use v 11.10.

Am I the only one with such a problem?

Comment: Goto about:config in Firefox on Windows and Linux, and check if 'general.smoothScroll' have the same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally FF is smooth. And other graphic intense apps too. The recent xorg + unity update fixed it.

Comment: Actually, it still doesn't seem to be fast as windows, but at least better than it was.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting graphic lag as well, but with the Gnome Shell. I read on a forum that changing the driver would solve the problem and it did! Let us see if this can solve your problem as well.

1. Open the `Additional Drivers` application.
2. Select the recommended nvidia driver for usage.
3. Follow the instructions issued by the application.

If I remember correctly, you will have to restart your computer in order for it to integrate the drivers into the kernel, and the next time you log in your problem might be solved.

Comment: Yes, i'm using that driver already. It doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to consider disabling IPV6 in Firefox.  I find that this speeds my browsing experience up considerably.  As an experiment, try loading Opera or Chromium to see if your browsing experience improves significantly.  If it does, you way want to check out [these directions](http://thedaneshproject.com/posts/disable-ipv6-in-firefox-3/) -

Comment: I have FF7, and it's set to false. Thanks anyways!

Comment: And? You need to set it to true... so that disableIPv6 is true and you have disabled it.

Comment: I don't have any problems with loading content. I'm talking about scrolling.